# Creating a 7 day live dashboard on Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

As the title says I'm trying to create a live dashboard in Tableau that updates every day showing the data for the last 7 days. I'm querying through SQL and then importing it in Tableau. Do I have to specify this requirement in my query or would there be some way to do it in the tableau itself. Thank you so much. I would really appreciate the help.

Disclaimer: I'm pretty novice in tableau and SQL.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This can be done with SQL. But to help you with this, we need more details: which database are you using? Which fields (types) does your tables contain?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date field in your table then you can use it as a filter and select relative date as the option for the filter and in the dialog that appears you can enter number of days for the days field. Since you want the live data for the last 7 days, you can enter 7 and you'll get the updated data each time.

Comment: Adding to @raxerz answer, use data source filter option. This will reduce the data loaded for the dashboard to only past 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying through SQL, put the filter for date/ timestamp in where condition itself like so:

```
DATE(date_column_filter) >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```